# State/Execution ID in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a problem with multiple executions of the same SSIS package. 
I would like to allow parallel executions each of which handles a subset of data.

So far, I am thinking of using some state variable, but I don't know where to store it.

One option is to use keep the connection open and use temp tables to coordinate the task load. However, temptables cause lots of compilation issues, and they are not maintable.

Are there any other ways to identify the current execution id of the package or scope of execution? I have found no state (either in memory or stored elsewhere) in SSIS so far which I can use to partition/isolate each execution.

Comment: You could do it the hard way. Make a workflowid package-variable and then for each different flow you have in your ssis-package make sure only one workflowid is used by each container, by setting up precedence constraints. Then you can call it via different jobs with different workflowid's which will go in different directions of your flow.

Comment: Maybe this is an XY problem.  It's not clear in your question WHY you have a problem with multiple concurrent executions.  Maybe there's a completely different way to solve your actual problem.

Comment: @TabAlleman I would like to allow parallel executions and reduce locking at the same time. That is, I'd like the packages to be quick, frequent, and independent of each other. If I can shard the executions somehow, it would be an optimal solution. Sure, I can have multiple packages, copies of each other with a variable as plaidDK suggests, but it is not maintainable.

Comment: You don't need copies of the package.  The same package can be running in multiple instances.  If there is locking happening, it's happening on the table, not on the package.

Comment: @Candide i didnt mean that you should have multiple packages. But multiple flows in one package each having different workflowid, then you can call each workflowid in your sqljob agent, and thereby you can execute your package paralelle

Comment: @plaidDK Interesting approach, however, each workflow is a copy of the other, isn't it? Meaning, I'd have to maintain N versions of the same workflow?

Comment: @Candide You need to maintain each workflow hence its different logic. So if you have 3 sequence containers doing 3 different logic, you will also have 3 workflowid's. Then you can set your sqljob agent to execute workflowid 1 and 3. Then it will execute the same package but go into the different sequence container containing your specific logic. And yes then you need to maintain each container regarding to its specific logic. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Candide just provided an answer, and the pictures are now available :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on my comments above you can try this. I dont know it is quite what your looking for, but maybe it can give you a hint to get further.

I am calling the example with workflowid 1. This is what i mean you can change in your SQL Job agent steps, and then change the parameter on each step, so fx you could add 2 steps executing workflowid 1 and workflowid 4. Then it will only run that sequence container where the constraint is success.

**Create a package variable**
[image: Create Package Parameter]

**Create your package flow**
[image: Create Package with local variable]

**Edit your SQL Task Get WorkflowID**
[image: Setup SQL Task to get workflowID]
**Add Parametermapping to your package variable**

[image: setup Parameter Mapping]

**Get the resultset into local variable called WorkflowIDrun**
[image: Setup Resultset]

**Make your precedence constraints so it only allows one id to pass through**
Notice: You could add parentworkflowid's so that you can diverse your flow inside the sequence container if you need some of the same logic
[image: Edit your precedence constraints]

**End result when package is run with workflowid 1**
[image: Package run with workflowid 1]

**Create a new SQL Job in your agent. Add the needed steps** Notice; I Created two steps for workflowid 1 and 2. Truncate and delete

[image: SQL Job setup]

**I then edit my step and correct the variable with the right value. This will be workflowid 1 for truncate and workflowid 2 for delete**
This could of cause also be in another job you do it, that depends on your needs.
[image: Step setup with correct workflowID]

Comment: I think the image part on this site is down atm. I only creates links and they are not accessible.

Comment: We are using project parameters to replace connection strings, but this is an interesting approach to use the parameters as execution IDs. In my case, the workflow is the same, I just need to execute it under a different context each time. So the degree of parallelism is based on the number of SQL Jobs configured. Thanks!